# How to change default font folder location on windows 11

Tags: windows, filesystems, fonts, parallels, user-folders

I'm looking to merge Windows font folder from parallels with the MacOS one. I think it's done via the Windows registry editor but I haven't figured out how it works yet so can someone help me with the command?

[image: Image of the Microsoft windows font folder]

Edit:
The directory I want to merge to is
**Macintosh HD/System/Library/Fonts**

Comment: You want to merge the font folders from two entirely different operating systems? That isn't going to work, given that Windows changed the way Fonts are installed with Windows 10+. What makes you think the Fonts are even compatible with one another?

Comment: I'm using a VM called parallels which allows me to run windows on mac. The equivalent directory of "Macintosh HD/System/Library/Fonts" on the windows side since everything is shared would be "Z:\System\Library\Fonts". I just want windows to use my mac fonts dir instead of installing them again on windows which is why I created this issue. For compatibility, most font file types are standardized so I see no issues there.

Comment: I am aware how you run Windows on Apple silicon. Doesn’t change the fact you can’t use Windows fonts on MacOS. The two operating systems handle fonts entirely differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Although the formats allow transferring fonts from PC to Mac,
you still need to *install* the font.

For example, installing a font on Windows requires registry updates.
Just copying a font into the Fonts folder is not enough.

However, you may transfer fonts files from one computer to the other
and *install* them, as long as the files are of a compatible format,